# How to execute bashscript on multiple ec2 instances at the same time

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, centos7

I have written a bash-script. Just by performin .`/script.sh` I can execute it at the moment on one node.
But it's need to be executed on multiple nodes. How can I execute one script on multiple nodes at the same time?

At the moment I'm using this:

```
for ip in $(<ALL_SERVERS_IP); do ...
```

But this is performing the installation not at the the same time. It's finished the first node and start to the second etc. I'm working on centos7

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting a `&` after your command.

```
for ip in $(<ALL_SERVERS_IP); do YOUR_COMMAND_OR_SCRIPT & done
```

Ampersand at the end will put your script in background, not waiting for script to end.

Comment: But will it execute all the commands on the same time on each server?

Comment: Not on exact same time, no. It will start the second node, right after **starting** the first one, and so on. It will not wait for finishing first node and then go to second.
Example
`$ echo "sleep 1"; sleep 2; echo "sleep 2"; sleep 2;`
will give you
`sleep 1  #waiting for 2 sec
sleep 2  #waiting for 2 sec`
Where this
`$ echo "sleep 1"; sleep 2 & echo "sleep"; sleep 2 & echo "done"`
will put the delays in the background and will list through commands in a heartbeat (just starting them).
`sleep 1
[1] 4820   #no wait, put in the background
sleep #2
[2] 7300  #no wait, put in the background
done`